# Create, and insert into, an Aerospike ordered map from Python

Tags: aerospike

I see [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/kvs/collections.html) for appending to a list in Aerospike, from Python, namely:

```
key = ('test', 'demo', 1)
rec = {'coutry': 'India', 'city': ['Pune', 'Dehli']}

client.put(key, rec)

client.list_append(key, 'city', 'Mumbai')
```

However I don't know how to add elements to a map in Aerospike, from Python, and I also don't know how to define said map as [sorted](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/modelling-time-series-data-top-performing-stocks-aerospike-using-sorted-maps/).

Essentially I am trying to model a time series as follows:

```
  ticker1: {intepochtime1: some_number, intepochtime2: some_other_number,...}
  ticker2: {intepochtime1: some_number, intepochtime2: some_other_number,...}
  ........
```

where the tickers are the record keys, so are indexed obviously, but also where the intepochtimes are integer JS-style integer timestamps and are *also indexed* by virtue of being stored in ascending or descending order and therefore easily range-queryable. How is this doable from Python?

Comment: Did you examine the API? Cannot check now if that is relevant enough, but there are calls for [adding items to the map](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_put) and for setting [map policy](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_set_policy) with predefined [ordering](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#map-policies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some sample code to get you started:
Also on github: https://github.com/pygupta/aerospike-discuss/tree/master/stkovrflo_Py_SortedMaps

```
import aerospike
from aerospike import predicates as p

def print_result((key, metadata, record)):
   print(record)

config = { 'hosts': [ ("localhost", 3000), ] }
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

map_policy={'map_order':aerospike.MAP_KEY_VALUE_ORDERED}

# Insert the records
key = ("test", "demo", 'km1')
client.map_set_policy(key, "mymap", map_policy)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '0', 13)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '1', 3)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '2', 7)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '3', 2)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '4', 12)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '5', 33)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '6', 1)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '7', 12)
client.map_put(key,  "mymap", '8', 22)


# Query for sorted value
print "Sorted by values, 2 - 14"
ret_val = client.map_get_by_value_range(key, "mymap", 2, 14, aerospike.MAP_RETURN_VALUE)
print ret_val

#get first 3 indexes 
print "Index 0 - 3"
ret_val2 = client.map_get_by_index_range(key, "mymap", 0, 3, aerospike.MAP_RETURN_VALUE)
print ret_val2



pgupta@ubuntu:~/discussRepo/aerospike-discuss/stkovrflo_Py_SortedMaps$ python sortedMapExample.py 
Sorted by values, 2 - 14
[2, 3, 7, 12, 12, 13]
Index 0 - 3
[13, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Question: do I have to set the map policy for every record and bin combination via the key? Or can I set a default map policy for the entire set?

Comment: You can do it in the operations themselves, for example [`map_put_items`](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_put_items). You'd set the 'map_order' map policies.

Comment: See updated github -- added two more files. You can essentially create a SI on the bin, then use the api calls if you want to do set wise.  One is a SI example for Lists and Maps, second used Map SI on set to do what you want at record level query.

Comment: BTW, there is no set level policy (none needed, per my set level code example) for map_policy.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Python documentation for Client.

Must be ver 3.8.4+
Create map policy :
Define one of the key ordered or key value ordered policies
http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#map-policies for map_order

Put map type bin but first define the map policy.
http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#id1
see map_set_policy(key, bin, map_policy)
then map_put()

Sorted maps are just regular maps but with map_order policy.

Comment: Yes I am using 3.11. Thanks for this documentation link - I think it would be preferable explicitly to copy and paste it into your answer if you'd like the bounty points awarded. Also I'll point out that the docs located on Aerospike.com that I linked to, namely, http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/usage/kvs/collections.html, are incomplete. I point this out because I'm guessing, given your new profile here on Stack Overflow, that you are associated with Aerospike the company so it might be worth ensuring that both of these separate sources of official Python docs are synchronised.

Comment: I think API reference is always a better link to go to because it is auto-updated with code changes.  If I get some time, I may write a code example for sorted maps in python - trust you have a use case - to help you get going.

Answer (score 0):

python3 mem leak fixed in client ver 2.0.8.

[image]